# _wp_page_template returns empty array in get_pages

Tags: php, wordpress

According to other's posts, and the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) for `get_pages()`, you can filter the array that's returned by pages only using a certain template type.

However, for me this isn't working, and I don't know why, I just get an empty array returned.

This is my exact code:

```
<?php $procedures = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'template-procedure-minimal.php'
)); //var_dump($procedures); ?>

<select name="procedureID" id="procedureID" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($procedures as $p) {
        echo '<option value="'.$p->ID.'"';
        if($p->ID == $bv_set->procedureID) {
            echo ' selected="selected"';
        }
        echo '>'.$p->post_title.'</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```

The template file I'm specificing is in the root of my current theme, along with the standard `page.php`, `single.php` etc. The template file exists, and is being used.

I can confirm there is something wrong when I change it to even `page.php`, the array is still empty when returned.

Is there anything I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the response below, this did solve my issue. However, I'd like to ask now if it's possible to have multiple page templates?

If I try the below, the array returned only contains the last template found in the array.

```
<?php $procedures = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => array('template-procedure.php', 'template-procedure-minimal.php')
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably add `hierarchical` parameter to your `get_pages` function like this:

```
<?php $procedures = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'template-procedure-minimal.php',
    'hierarchical' => 0
)); ?>
```

More details here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: `NOTE: This default value will prevent meta_key & parent page searches from finding sub-pages. You need to set 'hierarchical' => 0 for these parameters to work properly.` - Interesting! Thanks!